# RMStore "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit, rmstore

I've integrated RMStore in my project using cocoapod. The integration was successful and I've followed RMStore demo and integrated in app purchase logic with **receipt validation**.

**In receipt validation, instead of build number, version number is assigned and when I tested with AdHoc profile**,

**I received "Purchase failed" error.**

> I rectified this issue and replaced version with Build number and took
>   another build and while testing this build throws **"Couldn't connect
>   to Store" Error.**
>
> As mentioned in other stackoverflow links, I tried logging out of my
>   official id and tried with test id but error still there.
>
> FYI, though it doesn't work in simulator, While testing, I accidently
>   logged in using official id for testing...  will that create any
>   issues while testing in real device?

Comment: Did you test on a real device?
Usually, it just doesn't work on a simulator and works on a real device.

Comment: Yes, in real device it worked

Comment: Did you find any clue on this issue? Some users purchase successful, but some users fail with the error message "Couldn't connect to Store". Just don't know is it a issue related to Apple, or to me.

Comment: As it's mentioned, I was getting this error in simulator. In device it works. Are you testing in device? . Since you mentioned purchase successful for some users, it must be a problem with Apple.